# How to get Values from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have written a servlet code in com.company.abc which is

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        XYZ xyz = new XYZ();

        int value = xyz.fucn();

        request.setAttribute("value", value);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

page.jsp file under web folder

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>My JSP 'indexnewpage.jsp' starting page</title>
</head>

</body>
<%
    Object value = request.getAttribute("value");
%>
<p><%=value%></p>
<body>

</html>
```

now I want to see the value of Object value in the JSP page but i cant see that please help me out please correct the code if you find anything wrong in it or help me ut to get the values from servlet to the jsp page with some example code.

Comment: Do you have a web.xml? That is where you will map your servlet with a URL pattern.

Comment: Your code works for me. How are you running your code and what output you get? Did you map your servlet with URL in web.xml or using annotation like @WebServlet("/yourURL") in servlet class?

Comment: Please consider not using scriptlets.

Comment: The code looks good. Are you sure your servlet is invoked correctly and then the flow is transferred to the page.jsp afterwards? View the html source in your browser to see if you actually land on the page.jsp.

Comment: Hi Pshemo and Surge yeah i do have web.xml may be you can correct me by giving the right way to map in web.xml

Comment: in the web.xml i have written <servlet class>com.company.abc and <-Url pattern> /value. if this is wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it finally  the only thing which i missed is putting a / before page.jsp so it should be like /page.jsp.